# hbase doesn't start because of Master exiting error caused by java.lang.NumberFormatException

Tags: hadoop, hbase

### introduction

In version 1.1.4, I run the start-hbase.sh,find that regionserver is successfully started but the hbase master failed as follows:

### error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed construction of Master: class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.constructMaster(HMaster.java:2341)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.startMaster(HMasterCommandLine.java:233)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.run(HMasterCommandLine.java:139)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ServerCommandLine.doMain(ServerCommandLine.java:126)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.main(HMaster.java:2355)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "hdfs://dell06:60000"
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getInt(Configuration.java:1104)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.<init>(RSRpcServices.java:852)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.MasterRpcServices.<init>(MasterRpcServices.java:214)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.createRpcServices(HMaster.java:533)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.<init>(HRegionServer.java:531)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.<init>(HMaster.java:365)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.constructMaster(HMaster.java:2336)
        ... 5 more
```

### explain

the input string: "hdfs://dell06:60000" is the configuration of hbase.master.port,and the full hbase-site.xml as follows.

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
        <value>hdfs://dell06:12306/hbase</value>
        <description></description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.tmp.dir</name>
        <value>/tmp/hbase-${user.name}</value>
        <description></description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.master.port</name>
        <value>hdfs://dell06:60000</value>
        <description></description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
        <value>dell01,dell02,dell03,dell04,dell05,dell06</value>
        <description></description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
    <property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>5</value>
    </property>
    <property>
    <name>hbase.regionserver.handler.count</name>
    <value>30</value>
    </property>

</configuration>
```

i read the source code of this part but didn't get it!! Thanks in advance

Comment: Under hbase.master.port you should be mentioning only the port so the value should be just 60000

Comment: wow, thank you very much. I change this conf for some other reason, but forgot to restore it.. than you!